# How can I programatically add an entry to Cloudfront behaviour settings via .NET?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm unable to find any examples for this, has anyone done it via C# using AWSSDK?

```
Amazon.CloudFront.AmazonCloudFrontConfig config = new Amazon.CloudFront.AmazonCloudFrontConfig();
config.ServiceURL = "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/";

Amazon.CloudFront.AmazonCloudFrontClient cl = new AmazonCloudFrontClient("xx", "xxxx",RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
cl.GetDistribution("cloudfrontid").Dump();
```

It always answers I don't have any cloudfront distribution set up for this account:

```
No account found for the given parameters
```

Inner exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```